# Building with cocoa touch framework

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, tvos, bitcode

Is there any way how to have two versions of one framework in xcode, one build for simulator, one built for production and use the one in a project based on what am I building for? 
I have problems with making a fat framework for tvOS app (but this applies to iOS too) which requires bitcode so I thought something like that would be a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I use the below script for my framework project.

Add a Aggregate Target to your workspace. Under Build Phases -> Run Script add the below script.

```
#!/bin/sh

UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Step 1. Build Device and Simulator versions
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos  BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build
xcodebuild -target "${PROJECT_NAME}" -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build

# Step 2. Copy the framework structure (from iphoneos build) to the universal folder
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

# Step 3. Copy Swift modules from iphonesimulator build (if it exists) to the copied framework directory
SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule/."
if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" ]; then
cp -R "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/Modules/${PROJECT_NAME}.swiftmodule"
fi

# Step 4. Create universal binary file using lipo and place the combined executable in the copied framework directory
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework/${PROJECT_NAME}"

# Step 5. Convenience step to copy the framework to the project's directory
cp -R "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/${PROJECT_NAME}.framework" "${PROJECT_DIR}"

# Step 6. Convenience step to open the project's directory in Finder
open "${PROJECT_DIR}"
```

Comment: you are describing static framework aren't you? I am asking about dynamic one ...

Comment: @Ondrej Here is my script I use to create a fat framework: 1. `lipo -create -output "NAME" "Debug-iphonesimulator/NAME.framework/NAME" "Debug-iphoneos/NAME.framework/NAME"` 2. `cp -R Debug-iphoneos/NAME.framework ./NAME.framework` 3. `mv NAME ./NAME.framework/NAME` 4. `xcrun lipo -info NAME.framework/NAME` This might help you somehow. :)

Comment: And is that apple appstore safe?